# On Samsung Devices, Ripple and Reveal's fail if imageView animation is playing

Tags: android, android-animation, circularreveal

This only seems to occur on Samsung devices (tested on S7 and Tab S2).

**Problem**
If any animation is playing, all dialog ripple and reveal affects are stunted, stop half way, or do not play at all.

For example, this imageview animation has been started:

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.48f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(2000);

ivStatus.startAnimation(anim);
```

Then I touch a button in a dialog or start a reveal animation.
The animation either freezes at random points or stutters horribly.
In my code, some reveals are dialogs so it blocks the user from doing anything when the dialog reveal stops half way.

Edit: This also occurs when using a `progressView` such as `com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView`, which animates.

How can this be prevented/fixed? This works perfectly fine on non-samsung devices.

Example project at: https://github.com/behelit/SamsungAnimationFailSample

The image below has a frozen ripple, no touch is occurring at this point
[image: Ripple death]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to pause all animations onPause and resume in onResume.